# pool.query is not a function - Using npm mysql package to use connection pool

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm using [npm mysql package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), to create a connection pool to my [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) DataBase with `dbHandler.js` :

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: "path.to.host",
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: "dbname",
    debug: false
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

Then I call it inside `routesHandler.js`, to handle my SQL request :

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var pool = require("./dbHandler");

exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email = ?', [email], function(
        error,
        results,
        fields
    ) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                code: 400,
                failed: "Error ocurred"
            });
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                //Mail authorized
                res.send({
                    code: 200,
                    success: "Sucessfull login"
                });
            } else {
                //Mail unauthorized
                res.send({
                    code: 403,
                    failed: "Unauthorized mail"
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, but I can't seem to found a proper example... :/ 
I would gladly :) accept any suggestions or links about the way to handle the whole :

- Connections to database +
- SQL requests to database

But I'm getting that basic error message but I can't figure out how to get rid of it :

> TypeError: pool.query is not a function

Any pointers will be welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do `exports.pool = pool;`, so you must call the pool propriety like this `var pool = require("./dbHandler");`.

If you use `module.exports=pool` in your `dbHandler` then your code will work as is.

If not just use my answer  :

```js
var pool = require("./dbHandler").pool;

exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email = ?', [email], function(
        error,
        results,
        fields
    ) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                code: 400,
                failed: "Error ocurred"
            });
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                //Mail authorized
                res.send({
                    code: 200,
                    success: "Sucessfull login"
                });
            } else {
                //Mail unauthorized
                res.send({
                    code: 403,
                    failed: "Unauthorized mail"
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Just added the `.pool` and everything worked liked a charm!^^

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I tried most of the available solution but none of them are working and finally, I got the answer to my problem.

`dbHandler.js` file:

```js
var Pool = require('pg').Pool;

var pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'database_name',
    password: '#############',
    port: 5432,
});


module.exports = {pool};
```

`anotherfile.js`:

```js
let {pool: pool} = require('dbHandler');
// by this calling method I was able to use pool
```

Comment: This worked for me in 2021, other answers did not

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use `async/await` before the function like this :

```
exports.login = async function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
   await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.email = ?', [email], function(
        error,
        results,
        fields
    ) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({
                code: 400,
                failed: "Error ocurred"
            });
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                //Mail authorized
                res.send({
                    code: 200,
                    success: "Sucessfull login"
                });
            } else {
                //Mail unauthorized
                res.send({
                    code: 403,
                    failed: "Unauthorized mail"
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```